# How to expand current filename without 'test' in vimscript or UltiSnips

Tags: regex, vim, vim-plugin, ultisnips

I'm writing a snippet in which I need to get the current file name in vimscript. I can do this happily with `expand('%:t:r')` (as shown [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/how-do-i-get-the-name-and-extension-of-the-current-file)). However, I'd like to not only exclude '.js' from the filename, but also '.test'.

e.g.

If in `myName.test.js`, I would like to grab 'myName'

If in `myName.js`, I would also like to grab 'myName'

I'm doing this to create an UltiSnips snippet so other methods (e.g. regex) would also be useful

Comment: I don't know other parts of your question but here is how to grab the file name before the `.` using regex    /^([^\.]++)/    also see the demo on regex 101 https://regex101.com/r/lHiwpQ/1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `:t` and `:r` are filename modifiers. If you follow [`:help filename-modifiers`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#filename-modifiers), there's also a nifty (but little known) `:s?pat?sub?` modifier that can perform substitutions. As this can be combined with the other modifiers, all you need to do is match `.test` anchored to the end of the filename:

```
:echo expand('%:t:r:s?\.test$??')
```

There's no error if the substitution fails, so there's no need to make the match optional (via `\?`).